# Standard input stream redirection

Tags: io-redirection, cat, stdin

`stdin`: Generally standard input, referred to as `stdin`, comes from the keyboard.

When you type stuff, you're typing it on `stdin` (a standard input terminal). A standard input device, which is usually the keyboard, but Linux also allows you take standard input from a file.

For example:

```shell
cat < myfirstscript
```

This would tell `cat` to take input from the file `myfirstscript` instead of from the keyboard (This is of course the same as: `cat myfirstscript`).

Essentially what this boils down to is that the input for this command (`cat`) is no longer coming from where it was expecting to come from (the keyboard), but is now coming from a file.

I'm confusing something: it was expecting to come from (the keyboard), but is now coming from a file.

When you type a file on the keyboard (like: `cat myfirstscript`) isn't this a file in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

> Generally standard input, referred to as "stdin", comes from the keyboard.

That's very rarely the case! For example: when you boot it, our computer has run a couple thousand processes which read their standard input from something else than a keyboard before you come to type the first letter :)

> When you type stuff, you're typing it on stdin (a standard input terminal).

No, you type it into a keyboard, and a kernel driver understands these input events, and converts them into key codes, which are then emitted via a pseudo-tty to some terminal emulator.

That terminal emulator can choose to connect the stdin of the program it's running to that PTTY.

> (This is of course the same as: cat myfirstscript).

But that's only the case because `cat` is written such that the argument you pass to it gets interpreted as a file to be opened, and to be used *instead* of stdin.

When you do `cat < myfirstscript`, you tell your shell to 1. open the file `myfirstscript` (to get a file descriptor) and 2. to run `cat`, whereas the `stdin` stream gets replaced by the open file descriptor.

So, while the effect is the same, it's a pretty different mechanism!

> Essentially what this boils down to is that the input for this command (cat) is no longer coming from where it was expecting to come from (the keyboard), but is now coming from a File

`cat` never "expected" anything about the input stream; especially not that it comes from a keyboard (`cat` couldn't deal with a keyboard device at all. It needs the terminal to hand it the keypresses converted to *characters*).

> When you type a file on the keyboard (like: cat myfirstscript). isn’t this a file in the same way?

No.